# clearing checked radio button id

Tags: java, radio-button

I am working on a quiz app that displays options on radio buttons. The issue is that when I click on the next button to move to the next question, the id of the previously radio button is picked thereby causing me to get a wrong answer because whatever button that was clicked previously is what will be used to compare the answer of another question which result to wrong answer. For example, if the answer that I picked in question 1 was assigned to radio button one, when I click on the next button to move to the next question it will automatically pick whatever option that's assigned to radio button 1 also in the next question.The answer can only be correct only if the correct option for question 1 and 2 are option 1. Hopefully my question is a bit clear. Have updated my question with the full code. Please someone should help me out on how to resolve it

```
    public class QuizFragment extends Fragment {

    Button buttonNext;
    TextView tv, timing;
    RadioButton rb1, rb2, rb3, rb4;
    RadioGroup rg;
    int questionNumber, count = 1;
    int correctAnswer = 0;
    String rightAnswer=null ;
    String selectedOption = "Nothing";
    private QuestionViewModel viewModel;
    NavController navController;
    private String quizId,regNumber;
    private int generatedIndex;
    private AuthenticationViewModel authenticationViewModel;


    public QuizFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this,ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(
                getActivity().getApplication()
        )).get(QuestionViewModel.class);
        authenticationViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this,ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(
                getActivity().getApplication()
        )).get(AuthenticationViewModel.class);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_quiz, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        buttonNext = view.findViewById(R.id.button_next);
        regNumber = QuizFragmentArgs.fromBundle(getArguments()).getRegNumber();
        tv = view.findViewById(R.id.textview_question);
        timing = view.findViewById(R.id.textview_time);
        rb1 = view.findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
        rb2 = view.findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
        rb3 = view.findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
        rb4 = view.findViewById(R.id.radioButton4);
        rg = view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(view);
        quizId = QuizFragmentArgs.fromBundle(getArguments()).getQuizId();
        viewModel.setQuizId(quizId);
        loadData(view);
        timeCount();

        buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loadData(view);
            }
        });
    }
    private void loadData(View view){
        //generate a random number to get a question based on the generated index
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=1;i<=15;i++){
            list.add(i);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        generatedIndex =list.get(0);
        if (count ==11){
            buttonNext.setText("Submit");
        }else if (count >10){
            submitTest();
        }else {
            loadQuestions(view,generatedIndex);
        }
        //remove the index of the asked question
        list.remove(0);
    }

    private void loadQuestions(View view, int index){

        viewModel.getMutableLiveData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<QuestionModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<QuestionModel> questionModels) {
                
                rightAnswer = questionModels.get(index).getAnswer();
                tv.setText(questionNumber+"."+questionModels.get(index).getQuestion());
                rb1.setText(questionModels.get(index).getOption1());
                rb2.setText(questionModels.get(index).getOption2());
                rb3.setText(questionModels.get(index).getOption3());
                rb4.setText(questionModels.get(index).getOption4());
                verifyAnswer(view);
            }
        });
    }
    private void verifyAnswer(View view) {

        if(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId()!=-1) {
            RadioButton option = view.findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            selectedOption = option.getText().toString();

            if (selectedOption.equalsIgnoreCase(rightAnswer)) {
                correctAnswer += 2;
            } else {
                correctAnswer += 0;
            }
            rg.clearCheck();
            count +=1;
            questionNumber = count;
        }

    }
    private void submitTest(){
        authenticationViewModel.updateStudentWithScore(regNumber,correctAnswer);
        authenticationViewModel.getMutableLiveData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<FirebaseDatabase>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase) {
                //will check if there is any need for this later
                QuizFragmentDirections.ActionQuizFragmentToResultFragment action =
                        QuizFragmentDirections.actionQuizFragmentToResultFragment();
                action.setScore(correctAnswer);
                navController.navigate(action);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems like the issue might be related to how you handle radio button selections and clearing checks. Instead of using rg.clearCheck() immediately after checking the selected option, try moving it outside the if (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1) block. This way, it won't interfere with the next question's radio group.

Comment: I have moved it yet the issue still not resolved @Shubham Patel

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum.  This should be a comment.  You cannot comment until you have the necessary rep.  Please read [answer]